# formatting ol list counting number in html

Tags: html, css, html-lists

How to format only the background of the `list-index` using css?

```
<ol style="list-style-type:decimal">
    <li>Tagesordnung</li>
    <li>Pause</li>
    <li>Vorbesprechung</li>
    <li>Mittagessen</li>
    <li>Vortrag zum Thema "Komme nie zu fr&uuml;h zur Sache!"</li>
    <li>Pause</li>
    <li>Gem&uuml;tlicher Ausklang</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: What are you referring to by `list-index-backgrounds`?

Answer (score 5):

Use of css `list-style-position: outside;` would be enough?

CSS for your HTML code:

```
ol{
    background-color: red;
    list-style-position: outside;
}
ol li{
    background-color: white;
}
```

Here is jsfiddle example.
http://jsfiddle.net/RGKnu/1/

P.S.
If you want f.e. more space between background and list-item text you could use `text-indent`  css property with `li` selector.